# Adicionar uma linha fixa a cada 50 linhas CSV PHP

Tags: php, csv

Estou com um problema. Tenho um arquivo CSV com 490 linhas (em média, esse valor pode variar) e gostaria de adicionar 1 certo numero a cada 50 linhas.

Cada linha basicamente consiste de 10 dígitos numéricos e após esses dígitos, é criado uma nova linha (se não me engano, o divisor de linhas em CSV é a vírgula).

Exemplo:

```
1122222222
1199999999
1234567890
```

Gostaria que na linha 1 / linha 50 / linha 100 / linha 150 [...] fosse adicionado o seguinte número:

```
9977777777
```

Esse número seria igual em todas essas novas linhas. Levando em consideração que seria criado 1 número igual a cada 50 linhas (começando da primeira), eu teria 10 novos números.

Esse número são códigos de verificação que deve ser feito a cada 50 números afim de o bom funcionamento de um sistema.

A dúvida ao fim disso seria: Esse arquivo resultante teria 500 linhas (sendo 10 do número adicionado)?

Pois caso não der para fazer isso, eu tenho um script que está dividindo TODO um arquivo de 65000 linhas em 490 linhas. Talvez seja mais bacana adicionar os números fixos nesse arquivo grande e depois mandar dividir em 500 linhas. O que me dizem?

Outra coisa, precisaria que caso a opção seja usar o arquivo de 490 linhas, que ele busque TODOS os arquivos csv da pasta (talvez usando a função: `glob('*.CSV')` seguido de um foreach) já que o arquivo de 65000 linhas foi divido em vários com 490.  Caso seja feito no arquivo maior de 65000 linhas, não será necessário esse loop.

Será que seria possível fazer isso em PHP?
*** Isso tem que ter um output em arquivo. Ou seja, ou regravar o arquivo CSV ou criar um novo.

**SCRIPT DE DIVISÃO:**

```
<?php
$name = "bh";
$bigFile = fopen("$name.csv", "r");
$j = 0;

$content = file_get_contents("$name.csv");
$content = str_replace(';', '', $content);
file_put_contents("$name.csv", $content);

while(! feof($bigFile)) {
    $smallFile = fopen("$name $j.csv", "w");
    $j++;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 490 && ! feof($bigFile); $i++) {
        fwrite($smallFile, fgets($bigFile));

    }
    fclose($smallFile);

}
fclose($bigFile);

echo "Pronto!";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com base na ideia do @Jeferson Assis consegui adaptar o meu script para:

```
<?php
$name = "bh";
$bigFile = fopen("$name.csv", "r");
$j = 0;

$content = file_get_contents("$name.csv");
$content = str_replace(';', '', $content);
file_put_contents("$name.csv", $content);

while(! feof($bigFile)) {
    $smallFile = fopen("$name $j.csv", "w");
    $j++;

    for ($i = 0; $i < 500 && ! feof($bigFile); $i++) {
        if($i%50 == 0){
            fwrite($smallFile, "9977777777");
            fwrite($smallFile, PHP_EOL);
        }
        fwrite($smallFile, fgets($bigFile));

    }
    fclose($smallFile);

}
fclose($bigFile);

echo "Pronto!";
?>
```

Comment: @Jeferson Dessa forma ele adiciona 1 número a cada 50 linhas "aproximadamente". Ele adiciona na linha 1, na linha 52, linha 103, linha 154... Não sei o motivo do último dígito estar modificando... Não deveria ser 1~50~100~150...?

Comment: Teria que fazer a cada 49 então, pra linha inserida ser a 50 né...

Comment: Não sei ao certo...Mas dessa forma ai já me atendeu.

Comment: Bom, se você quer de 50 em 50, tem que ser `$i%49`.

Answer (score 1):

Na geração do seu CSV, na parte do looping você pode fazer o calcular o resto de 50.

Exemplo:

```
for($i = 0; $i< 100; $i++){
    if($i%5 == 0){
        echo '<hr />';
    }
    echo $i.'<br />';   
}
```

No exemplo ele adiciona uma linha a cada 5 registros (no seu caso linha no CSV)

Adequando o código para gerar seu excel:

```
$totalRegistro = 100;

for($i = 0; $i< $totalRegistro; $i++){
    if($i%50 == 0){
        //Aqui vai a parte onde você adiciona a linha com o valor 9977777777
    }

    //Aqui você adiciona o valor normalmente na sua planilha
}
```

Comment: Não seria o correto if($i%50) == 0 ?

Comment: tags html em csv? Não acho que vai dar certo... Acha que conseguiria adaptar isso a minha realidade? Fora que dessa forma ele não vai adicionar na primeira linha o número que preciso. Ele deve ser adicionado a CADA 50 linhas e também na primeira linha do arquivo.

Comment: Sim, é só você alterar esse valor para 50, eu coloquei 5 apenas para exemplificar com um menor número de linhas

Comment: O código de adicionar linha no seu CSV é apenas colocar aonde esta os `echo`, ele sempre vai adicionar na primeira linha, 0 % 50 == 0

Comment: E nessa parte '$i< 100' no lugar de 100 colocaria 490 ou 500? E como ficaria para adicionar na PRIMEIRA linha o número que preciso? Agora que me recordei: Essa solução não funcionaria para adicionar linha no arquivo, ele apenas daria um "print" na tela. Eu preciso que regrave no arquivo csv.

Comment: Adicionei na resposta mais ou menos como ficaria no seu código, a váriavel `$totalRegistro` é a quantidade de registro que você pretende adicionar no CSV

Comment: Sim... mas como disse, o PHP não vai salvar o resultado do echo no CSV.  Vou editar a pergunta com o script que estou usando para dividir o arquivo grande.

Comment: Você pode usar o [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) para ler o excel e adicionar as linhas e gerar um novo CSV, ou com o `fwrite` adicionar o conteudo, estilo o que você esta fazendo

Comment: Mas ai seria uma biblioteca a mais e um script que poderia ser simples, será ainda mais pesado. Será que para um problema simples desse não existe biblioteca do próprio php para gerenciar isso de forma simplificada não? A sua ideia é bacana, pena que não salva no CSV....